# Getting around the Same Origin Policy for a javascript page hosted locally

Tags: javascript, iframe, same-origin-policy

I am trying to design a JavaScript page which requires access to the content of an iframe or iframes, hosted on a different domain, which I do not have access to.

This page will only be hosted locally, meaning that I can use --disable-web-security on Chrome, but I would ideally like it to be an easily transferable page to give to a few other people who can use it without having to be drilled about the importance of not actually browsing the internet in the same instance of Chrome as this page is used.

I realize writing this that it possibly sounds like an attempt to disguise some malicious, if very amateurish intentions, but I assure you that is not the case. Basically I am designing an alternative selling manager front-end for an eBay business that can be distributed to employees to make a few tasks much easier. The only way I can see to do what I want is to access the standard eBay page through an iframe, as I will need to be able to interact with it from the parent.

Comment: Just throwing out ideas: wouldn't this be a case for an in-house chrome extension?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the eBay API: https://go.developer.ebay.com/ ?

Comment: Thank you both for your responses - I wasn't actually aware of the developers API of eBay, I have since signed up to it and I am going to try to figure it out but I think the main reason might be it is outside my skillset. The documentation is practically non-existent, or at least not entirely helpful for someone at my level. Some worked examples would be nice with perhaps some fully working scripts to look at, all I see is a bunch of inscrutable XML data that I have no idea what to do with. I guess I will keep at it though.

Comment: Hmm, and perhaps I am mistaken but after some experimentation it seems the Same Origin Policy still applies to XMLHTTPRequests, such as those I would be making to the eBay API. As far as I can tell this seems to severely limit the usefulness of javascript when accessing the API...

Answer (score -2):

If you dont have access to the iframe i dont know any way to get the access.

You probably need something like cross window messaging here.